# Ant: Jar File with src folder in it

Tags: java, ant, jar

I have a very big problem. I just created with ant a jar file and everything works, but in the jar file the src folder is ommited, but I need it because I'm referrencing a file from the application.

I.e. I have the following structure in my project ProjectName/src/org/nexLevel/nextLevel/Main.java. I also have ProjectName/config/settings.properties.

When I know build a jar file with ant I get only the folders org/nexLevel/nextLevel/Main.java but not the src folder. How can I get the src folder in my .jar?

Here is my ant script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="complete build" name="Create runnable jar file">
    <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
    <property name="lib.dir" location="lib" />
    <property name="build.dir" location="bin" />
    <property name="dist.dir" location="dist" />
    <property name="docs.dir" location="docs" />
    <property name="config.dir" location="config" />
    <property name="build.sysclasspath" value="last" />

    <path id="project-classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
    </path>

    <target name="remove release">
        <delete dir="${dist.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean build">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="clean docs">
        <delete dir="${docs.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="clean build">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" debug="on" target="1.8" source="1.8">
            <classpath refid="project-classpath" />
            <compilerarg value="-Xlint:none" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="docs" depends="clean docs, compile">
        <mkdir dir="${docs.dir}" />
        <javadoc packagenames="src" sourcepath="${src.dir}" destdir="${docs.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <include name="**" />
            </fileset>
        </javadoc>
    </target>

    <target name="build jar" depends="remove release, compile">
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
        <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/myApp.jar">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.nextLevel.nextLevel.Main" />
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="." />
            </manifest>

            <fileset dir="${build.dir}" />
            <zipfileset dir="config" prefix="config" />
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/**" src="lib/postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar" />
        </jar>
        <antcall target="clean build" />
    </target>

    <target name="complete build" depends="docs, build jar, clean build" />
</project>
```

Comment: ant target name with white space. Calling multiple targets will become difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jar task only includes build.dir, try adding src.dir to the jar as well

```
<fileset dir="${build.dir}" />
<fileset dir="." includes="**/*.java"/>
```

Comment: This did not create the src directory. No change. :(

Comment: Slight modification, added includes attribute

Comment: Another modification. This should create the src directory in the jar itself with all the java files in it.

Comment: Thank you. Now the src directory gets created with all the neccessary folders in it but at the same time there is still the old org/... directory. I.e. I have now two directories, first src/org/... and second org/... How can I get rid of the org/... directory?

Comment: Is there a ProjectName/org directory in your project structure and do you need it?

Comment: no there is only one in ProjectName/src/org but not in ProjectName/org.